# webpack config proxy request body logging

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy-middleware

Webpack dev server proxy config documentation seen here:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy

says it uses http-proxy-middleware:

https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-events

Using the `onProxyRes` function documented in the above link I do the following:

```
function onProxyRes(proxyRes, req, res) {
    proxyRes.headers['x-added'] = 'foobar';     // add new header to response
    delete proxyRes.headers['x-removed'];       // remove header from response
    console.log(req.headers)                    // log headers
    console.log(req.body)                  // undefined
    console.log(proxyReq.body)             // undefined
}
```

My problem, although everything else works great - I cannot log the Request Body - it returns `undefined`

Anyone know how to read the request body for debugging purposes? Do I somehow need to use the npm `body-parser` module? If so, how? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried logging the request with the express [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) module but it caused the requests to hang. Using the [body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body) module to log the request body fixed it.

```
const anyBody = require('body/any')
onProxyReq(proxyReq, req, res) {
    anyBody(req, res, function (err, body) {
        if (err) console.error(err)
        console.log(body)
    })
})
```

Note that I also used this same approach inside express as follows:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    anyBody(req, res, function (err, body) {
        if (err) console.error(err)
        console.log(body)
    })
    next()
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 4):

I solved a similar problem using `body-parser`.

I was trying to modify the request body before sending it to server, and it caused the request to hang maybe because, altering the body, the `Content-Length` of the request was no more matching (causing it to be truncated).

The solution was "resizing" `Content-Length` before writing the new request body:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');   

devServer: {
    before: function (app, server) {
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
    },
    onProxyReq: function (proxyReq, req, res) {
        req.body = {
            ...req.body,
            myProperty: "myPropertyValue"
        };

        const body = JSON.stringify(req.body);

        proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(body));

        proxyReq.write(body);
    }
}
```

Not sure, but in your case it could be that the request has been truncated by adding/removing headers, causing it to hang.

Comment: THANK YOU! Finally a clean solution.